# PHP DB2 DLL for PHP 5.3.8

Tags: php, dll, db2

Where can i get the php 5.3.8 dll extension to enable connection to a DB2 database. I tried searching the net and was unable to find any download links. :(

regards,
V

Answer (score 1):

You can find many of this info here

http://sourceforge.net/projects/db2mc/files/

Answer (score 1):

I tried download dlls from various sources but at the end XAMPP was the solution. If you install this application server [download from XAMPP home page.](https://www.apachefriends.org/hu/download.html)
This contains the a php and within a php.ini and the right dlls - so it worked for me.

If you are trying to connect to zOS or iSeries systems then you might face licensing issues too..